# My app keeps resetting after I close it

Tags: java, android

My app keeps resetting after I close it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    ImageView IMG ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IMG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button pickBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickBtn);

        pickBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pickImg();
            }
        });

    }

    private void pickImg() {
        new MaterialFilePicker()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withRequestCode(1)
                .withFilter(Pattern.compile(".*\\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$"))
                .withHiddenFiles(true)
                .withTitle("Sample title")
                .start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == FILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String filePath = data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH);
            // Do anything with file
            File imgFile = new  File(filePath);
            if(imgFile.exists()){
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                IMG.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My app is only filled with one button and one image default. With the button I can pick an image to replace the default image.

But when I close the app and open it again the image is back to default.

How to make it show the last picked image when I start the app??

Comment: You may use something like shared preferences to store the selection, or maybe consider using SQLite to store it.

Comment: can give a link for example ? ty :D

Comment: Just Google for these things, or search Stack Overflow.  You'll find a ton of useful resources.

Answer (score 1):

If this app is performing simple and offline task, you could use [Shared Preference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java) to store the location of the Image.  When onCreate, check whether the sharedpreference object is null or not, if not, load with the value stored.